# Search criteria based on few parameter Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, search, eloquent

This search works for me only when I fill all the fields correctly. My wish is that when I fill only one field, I will exclude results only relevant to this field.
Example if I fill only 'mark' field with 'Audi'  got my mark name.  My function is currently returning the results only if all fields are filled. If I fill one field, it returns an empty array. Also, I'm not sure if this function is well written, I followed the tutorial. Look code:

```
public function searchFilterCar(Request $request, Car $car){
    if($request->has('car_type')){
        if($request->has('mark')){
            if($request->has('model')){
                if($request->has('fuel')){
                    if($request->has('circuit')){
                        return $car->where('car_type', $request->input('car_type'))
                                    ->where('mark', $request->input('mark'))
                                    ->where('model', $request->input('model'))
                                    ->where('fuel', $request->input('fuel'))
                                    ->where('circuit', $request->input('circuit'))
                                    ->get();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Separate every `->where` and put it into relevant if condition. at the end call something like `$car->get()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate the conditions into several if statements, the where works on the existing results so you will be continuing from previous `where`. Its should something like this:

```
    if($request->has('car_type')){
        $car = $car->where('car_type', $request->input('car_type'));
    }

    if($request->has('mark')){
        $car = $car->where('mark', $request->input('mark'));
    }

    ....

    return $car->get();
```

It might look a bit crude but it decreases the size of the code block and it works

Comment: Okey now criteria not work property. I got all results from cars.


    public function searchFilterCar(Request $request, Car $car)
    {
        if ($request->has('car_type')) {
            $car->where('car_type', $request->input('car_type'));
        }
        if ($request->has('mark')) {
            $car->where('mark', $request->input('mark'));
        }
        if ($request->has('model')) {
            $car->where('model', $request->input('model'));
.......
        return $car->get();
    }

Comment: Hmmm can you check if it is entering the if statements? Also try something like `$car = $car->where('car_type', $request->input('car_type'));`

Comment: $car = $car->where('car_type', $request->input('car_type')); 
This is work perfectly. Thank you man.

Comment: Anytime mate. Please accept my answer. Ill edit it as well

Answer (score 0):

Another way similar to Khaldoun Nd's answer would be to use query conditionals. It allows you to remove the subsequent if statements.

The code would become something like that:

```php
return $car
    ->when($request->car_type, function ($query, $type) {
        return $query->where('car_type', $type);
    })
    ->when($request->mark, function ($query, $mark) {
        return $query->where('mark', $mark);
    })
    // Chain the other conditions like the previous ones...
    ->get();
```

For reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses